# Remove duplicate values in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am learning mongodb using python with tornado.I have a mongodb collection, when I do

```
db.cal.find()

{     
    "Pid" : "5652f92761be0b14889d9854",
    "Registration" : "TN 56 HD 6766",
    "Vid" : "56543ed261be0b0a60a896c9",
    "Period" : "10-2015",
    "AOs": [
        "14-10-2015",
        "15-10-2015",
        "18-10-2015",
        "14-10-2015",
        "15-10-2015",
        "18-10-2015"
    ],
    "Booked": [
        "5-10-2015",
        "7-10-2015",
        "8-10-2015",
        "5-10-2015",
        "7-10-2015",
        "8-10-2015"
    ],
    "NA": [
        "1-10-2015",
        "2-10-2015",
        "3-10-2015",
        "4-10-2015",
        "1-10-2015",
        "2-10-2015",
        "3-10-2015",
        "4-10-2015"
    ],

    "AOr": [
        "23-10-2015",
        "27-10-2015",
        "23-10-2015",
        "27-10-2015"
    ]
}
```

I need an operation to remove the duplicate values from the `Booked,NA,AOs,AOr`. Finally it should be

```
{
     "Pid" : "5652f92761be0b14889d9854",
      "Registration" : "TN 56 HD 6766",
      "Vid" : "56543ed261be0b0a60a896c9",
      "AOs": [
        "14-10-2015",
        "15-10-2015",
        "18-10-2015",

      ],
      "Booked": [
        "5-10-2015",
        "7-10-2015",
        "8-10-2015",

      ],

      "NA": [
        "1-10-2015",
        "2-10-2015",
        "3-10-2015",
        "4-10-2015",

      ],

      "AOr": [
        "23-10-2015",
        "27-10-2015",

      ]
}
```

How do I achieve this in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

## Working solution

I have created a working solution based on JavaScript, which is available on the mongo shell:

```js
var codes = ["AOs", "Booked", "NA", "AOr"]

// Use bulk operations for efficiency
var bulk = db.dupes.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

db.dupes.find().forEach(
  function(doc) {

    // Needed to prevent unnecessary operatations
    changed = false
    codes.forEach(
      function(code) {
        var values = doc[code]
        var uniq = []

        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          // If the current value can not be found, it is unique
          // in the "uniq" array after insertion
          if (uniq.indexOf(values[i]) == -1 ){
            uniq.push(values[i])
          }
        }

        doc[code] = uniq

        if (uniq.length < values.length) {
          changed = true
        }

      }
    )

    // Update the document only if something was changed
    if (changed) {
      bulk.find({"_id":doc._id}).updateOne(doc)
    }
  }
)

// Apply all changes
bulk.execute()
```

Resulting document with your sample input:

```js
replset:PRIMARY> db.dupes.find().pretty()
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("567931aefefcd72d0523777b"),
  "Pid" : "5652f92761be0b14889d9854",
  "Registration" : "TN 56 HD 6766",
  "Vid" : "56543ed261be0b0a60a896c9",
  "Period" : "10-2015",
  "AOs" : [
    "14-10-2015",
    "15-10-2015",
    "18-10-2015"
  ],
  "Booked" : [
    "5-10-2015",
    "7-10-2015",
    "8-10-2015"
  ],
  "NA" : [
    "1-10-2015",
    "2-10-2015",
    "3-10-2015",
    "4-10-2015"
  ],
  "AOr" : [
    "23-10-2015",
    "27-10-2015"
  ]
}
```

## Using indices with `dropDups`

This simply does not work. First, as per version 3.0, this option no longer exists. Since we have 3.2 released, we should find a portable way.

Second, even with dropDups, the documentation clearly states that:

> **dropDups** boolean : MongoDB indexes only the first occurrence of a key and removes all ***documents*** from the collection that contain subsequent occurrences of that key.

So if there would be another document which has the same values in one of the billing codes as a previous one, the whole document would be deleted.

Comment: You could just use one of the method shown in [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array) to remove the duplicate from those array and then use the `$set` operator with bulk operations to update the documents. Also note that MongoDB 3.2 deprecates Bulk() and its associated methods.

Comment: Neither Jquery nor ecma 6 are available on the shell, right? ;) I fail to see where identifying uniques is inferior. But good point with 3.2, I'll add the soltion with that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the "dropDups" syntax here first because it has been "deprecated" as of MongoDB 2.6 and removed in [MongoDB 3.0](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#remove-dropdups-option) and will not even work.

To remove the duplicate from each list you need to use the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)  class in python.

```
import pymongo


fields = ['Booked', 'NA', 'AOs', 'AOr']
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.test
collection = db.cal
bulk = colllection.initialize_ordered_op()
count = 0
for document in collection.find():
    update = dict(zip(fields, [list(set(document[field])) for field in fields])) 
    bulk.find({'_id': document['_id']}).update_one({'$set': update})
    count = count + 1
    if count % 200 == 0:
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = colllection.initialize_ordered_op()

if count > 0:
    bulk.execute()
```

---

MongoDB 3.2 [deprecates](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api) `Bulk()` and its associated methods and provides the [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) method. This method is available from Pymongo 3.2 as [`bulk_write()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write). The first thing to do using this method is to import the [`UpdateOne`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.UpdateOne) class.

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne


requests = [] # list of write operations
for document in collection.find():
    update = dict(zip(fields, [list(set(document[field])) for field in fields])) 
    requests.append(UpdateOne({'_id': document['_id']}, {'$set': update}))
collection.bulk_write(requests)
```

---

The two queries give the same and expected result:

```
{'AOr': ['27-10-2015', '23-10-2015'],
 'AOs': ['15-10-2015', '14-10-2015', '18-10-2015'],
 'Booked': ['7-10-2015', '5-10-2015', '8-10-2015'],
 'NA': ['1-10-2015', '4-10-2015', '3-10-2015', '2-10-2015'],
 'Period': '10-2015',
 'Pid': '5652f92761be0b14889d9854',
 'Registration': 'TN 56 HD 6766',
 'Vid': '56543ed261be0b0a60a896c9',
 '_id': ObjectId('567f808fc6e11b467e59330f')}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried "Distinct()" ?

Link: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

**Specify Query with distinct**

The following example returns the distinct values for the field sku, embedded in the item field, from the documents whose dept is equal to "A":

```
db.inventory.distinct( "item.sku", { dept: "A" } )
```

The method returns the following array of distinct sku values:

```
[ "111", "333" ]
```

Comment: Which would not reduce the data saved.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you want to remove duplicate dates from the collection, so you can add a unique index with the dropDups: true option:

```
db.bill_codes.ensureIndex({"fieldName":1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

For more reference: 
[db.collection.ensureIndex() - MongoDB Manual 3.0](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)

Note: Back up your database first in case it doesn't do exactly as you're expecting.

Comment: That would only drop other documents which have the exact same value for one of the fields.

Comment: i get the error:{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "errmsg" : "exception: bad index key pattern { Registration: \"TN 56 HD
6766\", Pid: \"5652f92761be0b14889d9854\" }: Unknown index plugin 'TN 56 HD 676
'",
        "code" : 67,
        "ok" : 0
}

Comment: Instead of name and nodes into criteria, you have to mention your collection key index.

Comment: This is not only outdated, it is plainly wrong and would be outright dangerous if not for the suggestion for taking a backup. The deprecated `dropDups` drops all *documents* which happen to have the same values for a key in the index, not duplicate values.